# eliminar iteraciones innecesarias

Tags: javascript

El siguiente algoritmo calcula los números perfectos dado un rango de números.

Un número perfecto es aquél que es igual a la suma de sus divisores, exceptuando él mismo 
`(1 + 2 + 3) = 6` por lo tanto `6` es un número perfecto

=====

Este algoritmo funciona correctamente, pero lo que me pidieron fue eliminar las iteraciones innecesarias y no tengo idea de como podría implementarlo. Si alguno de ustedes tiene idea seria de gran ayuda

```
  function NumerosPerfectosRango(numero) {
    for(let i = 1;i <= numero; i++){ // i es el número que vamos a comprobar
      let suma = 0;
      for(let j = 1;j <= i / 2; j++){ // j son los divisores. Se divide desde 1 hasta i/2
        if(i % j == 0){
         suma = suma + j; // si es divisor se suma
        }
      }
      if(i == suma){ // si el numero es igual a la suma de sus divisores es perfecto
        alert(suma);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Explica que hace el algoritmo, da más detalles

Comment: este algoritmo calcula los numeros perfectos dado un rango de numeros

Comment: y que es un numero perfecto? cuando hagas una pregunta, explica todo el contexto por favor.

Comment: ¿Hay algún problema con el código? Si funciona, entonces está bien. Si buscas eficiencia, puedes intentar refactorizarlo, y si te da problemas, entonces si que tu pregunta podría ser mejor recibida. Tal como está actualmente tu pregunta, parece *code review*, y eso está un poco fuera de tema. Saludos

Comment: Creo que primero sería mejor que extrajeras el código que comprueba si es número perfecto a una función, y luego ya meterte a simplificar dicha función, quitando iteraciones. Necesitarías explicar un poco más, pues no todo el mundo sabe las condiciones para un número perfecto

Comment: es que claramente sobra una iteracion.. para que iteras sobre el numero, si solo tenes que iterar sobre los numeros menores que el para buscar sus divisores y luego de eso sumarlos? a veces, explicando el codigo, encuentras la solucion

Comment: el algoritmo funciona, pero me piden eliminar las iteraciones innecesarias, y no tengo idea de como hacerlo, estoy buscando ideas de como podría implementarlo

Comment: Si el rango donde lo quieres evaluar está dentro de los números perfectos conocidos, puedes agregar la condicion que solo son pares según la siguiente conjetura "Los números perfectos de Euclides son todos pares ya que uno de los factores es una potencia de 2. Pero nada prueba, por el momento" y también puedes considerar otra conjetura.

Comment: (gbianchi) quizas tengas razon, pero sin le quito la iteracion sobre el numero no sabria como implementarlo,  esta es la manera que pude hacerlo, podrias darme un ejemplo de como seria si que quito la iteracion sobre el numero

Comment: -ange tienes razon de hecho yo realice este mismo algoritmo con la formula de euclides euler pero no me lo aceptaron

Comment: https://juancaval26.github.io/numeroPerfectos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes una manera que, más que simplificarlo, lo hace más eficiente. Hay una manera más eficiente de encontrar los divisores de un número `n`. No es necesario comprobar todos los posibles valores hasta `n/2`. Si un número `i` es divisor de `n`, entonces `n/i` también lo es, de modo que sólo es necesario comprobar desde `i=2` hasta `sqrt(n)`. Otra optimización es que `1` es siempre un divisor, por lo tanto no es necesario comenzar el ciclo en `1` com la `suma=0`, sino en `2`, ya siempre nuestra suma contendrá el valor `1`.

Aquí debajo dejo el código optimizado. Verás que la ejecución toma un tiempo, pero si cambias el método de chequeo y pones que que tienes, el tiempo de chequeo de todo el rango se vuelve muuuuuyyyyyyyyyyy leeeeeeeennnntoooooo.... ;)

```js
function EsPerfecto(n) {
    let sum = 1;
  
    for (let i = 2; i*i < n; i++){
    if (n%i==0)
    {
      if(i*i!=n)
        sum = sum + i + n/i;
      else
        sum=sum+i;
    }
  }
  
  if (sum == n && n != 1)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}


function NumerosPerfectosRango(numero) {
  for(let i = 1;i <= numero; i++){ // i es el número que vamos a comprobar
    if (EsPerfecto(i))
      console.info(i);
  }
}

console.clear();
NumerosPerfectosRango(1000000);
```

Tienes otra posible optimización. Aún no se ha demostrado que existan números perfectos que sean impares, y tampoco se han encontrado en los cálculos que se han hecho hasta el momento.

Answer (score 1):

Primero, siempre que uses listas de datos fijos, intenta precalcular. En este caso concreto, como la mayoría de números perfectos tienen muchísimos dígitos, por comodidad, los calcularemos.
Primero, si observas la definición de "números perfectos" dice:
Los números perfectos son generados por la formula:
`Math.pow(2,p-1)*(Math.pow(2,p)-1)`  donde `p` y `Math.pow(2,p)-1` son primos.
Estos números primos pueden precalcularse y guardarlos en una matriz.
En este caso concreto guardaremos los 12 primeros **(2,3,5,7,13,17,19,31,61,89,107,127)**, ya que a partir del 13, JS en incapaz de almacenar el resultado al ser demasiado grande (el valor máximo lo sabremos con `Number.MAX_VALUE` )
Una vez tenemos los primos adecuados, solo hay que crear una matriz con los 12 resultados, y que la función la consulte.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const primoPerfecto=[2,3,5,7,13,17,19,31,61,89,107,127]; // JS es incapaz de almazenar el resuldado con primos mayores.
var perfecto=[]; // Se podria usar directamente la lista de los 11 primeros números perfectos.
for (let i=0;i<primoPerfecto.length;i++) {
    let p = primoPerfecto[i];
    perfecto.push(Math.pow(2,p-1)*(Math.pow(2,p)-1));
}
    
function NumerosPerfectosRango(numero) {
    var resultado=[];
    for (let i=0; i<perfecto.length && perfecto[i]<=numero ; i++){
        resultado.push(perfecto[i]);
    }
    return resultado;
}

console.log ("Números perfectos hasta el 10.000",NumerosPerfectosRango(10000));
```

NOTA: Parece que realmente JS solo es capaz de mostrar un resultado correcto hasta el "primo perfecto" nº7 (y no el 12), ya que a partir del 8 guarda el resultado en notación científica y (creo) empieza a perder decimales, así que no obtenemos el número real (o almenos no se muestran correctamente usando .toLocaleString() )
Así que, en Javascript, lo mejor és simplemente guardar los 7 primeros valores, ya que es incapaz de mostrar mas allà.

```
var perfecto=[6,28,496,8128,33550336,8589869056,137438691328];
```

Conclusión: JavaScript no es una herramienta adecuada para trabajar con números grandes, al menos directamente.

Comment: Utilizando la demostración de Euclides, este método que aplicas, debes tener precalculada la lista de números primos, pero si te lo puedes permitir este es el método más rápido y menos costoso en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: La lista de primos aptos también se podría calcular, pero como en este caso en concreto los valores usables son pocos (12), no tendría sentido.
A no ser claro, que el profesor quiera ver como los calculas. En ese caso, aconsejo calcular los primos hasta el 127, argumentando que es el mayor usable por la herramienta usada)

Comment: muchas gracias a todos por sus aportes, no sabia como implementarlo con la formula de auclides euler para sacar los números por rango,  y esto fue de gran ayuda, para aclarar mis dudas. y ojala fuera para un examen este algoritmo, fue para una entrevista.

Comment: Ojo con la nota que he añadido. JS solo es capaz de mostrar un resultado correcto hasta el "primo perfecto" nº7 (el 19)

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenido Juan. Bueno, para un mayor entendimiento voy a agarrar tu código como ejemplo:

En primer lugar, aclarar que como dicen el los comentarios de tu pregunta, el primer *for()* está demás, ya que es valor que necesitas comprobar lo estas enviando en el parámetro de entrada.

En segundo lugar,  la comprobación de la igualdad entre el numero y la suma debería estar dentro del segundo *for()*, y una vez que esta comparación sea verdadera deberías cortar ahí las demás iteraciones. Para eso puedes hacer uso de **break**:

```
function NumerosPerfectosRango(numero) {
    let suma = 0;
    for( let j = 1 ; j <= numero / 2 ; j++){ // j son los divisores. Se divide desde 1 hasta i/2
        if(numero % j == 0){
            suma = suma + j; // si es divisor se suma
        }
        if(numero == suma){ // si el numero es igual a la suma de sus divisores es perfecto
            alert('El numero es perfecto');
            console.log('El numero es perfecto');
            break;
        }
        console.log(j) // mostramos las iteraciones q realiza el ciclo for()
    }
}
```

Luego del alert y de la comparación entre suma y numero, puse dos *console.log()* para que puedas notar la diferencia entre usar el break y no usarlo. Solo ejecútalo con y sin el break para ver la diferencia.

Comment: si se nota la diferencia, cuando encuentra la condicion para el ciclo, y muestra el numero perfecto, buen aporte, pero esto solo sirve para saber si un numero es perfecto o no.  se puede agregar un continue, donde esta el console.log(j) para que salga de una el quinto numero perfecto de lo contrario se queda colgado un rato,.

Comment: exacto @juan, a partir de ahí sacas la lógica para lo demás.

Answer (score 1):

Según la **Wikipedia** un **número perfecto** cumple con la propiedad de que también es un **número hexagonal**, y la secuencia de **números hexagonales** está definida por la fórmula **2n^2 - n**, de esta forma los primeros **números hexagonales** serían:

```
1, 6, 15, 28, 45, 66, 91, 120, 153, 190
```

Otra de las cosas que podemos optimizar del código es la obtención de los divisores de un número, resulta que los divisores del número se encuentran debajo de su raíz cuadrada, así por ejemplo, hallemos los divisores de **100**, su raíz cuadrada es **10**, y tenemos que iterar solamente de **1** hasta **10** para hallar todos sus divisores, de esta forma obtenemos las parejas de divisores:

```
1;100, 2;50, 4;25, 5;20, 10
```

Una vez aclarado todo esto te propongo el siguiente algoritmo:

```
function NumerosPerfectos(numero)
{
   var n = 1;
   var numAux = 0;
   var numerosPerfectos = [];
   var divisores = [];

   while(numAux <= numero)
   {
      numAux = (2 * n * n) - n; //nos movemos solamente por la secuencia de los números hexagonales
      n++;

      //Ahora procedemos a hallar todos los divisores del número hexagonal obtenido
      var raizCuadrada = Math.sqrt(numAux);

          raizCuadrada = Math.trunc(raizCuadrada);

      for (var i = 2; i < raizCuadrada ; i++) 
      {
         if(numAux % i == 0)
         {
            divisores.push(i);
            divisores.push(numAux / i);
         }
      }

      let suma = divisores.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) + 1;

      if(suma == numAux)
      {
         numerosPerfectos.push(numAux);
      }
   }
}
```

Lo que se hace aquí es movernos por la secuencia de **números hexagonales**, a cada **número hexagonal** le hallamos sus divisores y los guardamos en un arreglo, después sumamos todos los elementos de ese arreglo y preguntamos si esa suma es igual al número, de ser igual quiere decir que es un **número perfecto**.

Referencia: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_perfecto

Comment: esta formula estaria mas legible de esta menera pienso: numAux = ((2*n) ** 2) - n);

Comment: @juancamilovalderrama, mmm, pues no, tu multiplicas 2 * n y despues elevas esa multiplicacion al cuadrado, y en realidad lo que debes hacer es elevar n al cuadrado y despues multiplicar esa elevacion por 2, (2*n)**2 es diferente de 2*n*n

Comment: tienes razon. este seria su equivalente (2 * p ** 2);